# Android Data Binding do not work after proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-databinding

Link to project - [File manager](https://github.com/westman2000/WMFileManager)

After i'm enabling obfuscation, application crash, when i try to show fragment from library project that use data binding.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcorp/wmsoft/android/lib/filemanager/databinding/WmFmFileManagerViewLayoutBinding;
at corp.wmsoft.android.lib.filemanager.ui.widgets.nav.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

But Android Studio->Build->Analyze APK, show that i have this class inside APK:

[image: Analyze APK screenshot]

library project **proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class corp.wmsoft.android.lib.filemanager.databinding.** { *; }
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this happen for the application itself or is it when you're running tests against it?

Comment: no tests. i just run application with enabled minifyEnabled and shrinkResources in library build.gradle

Comment: @westman Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @westman facing same issue. Is there any solution for this?